# VirtualBox и Windows 10: не удается подключиться к серверу, запущенному на VirtualBox

Tags: windows, nginx, virtualbox, виртуальная-машина

Да, в интернете полно статей по этой теме. И я их перепробовав, не смог решить проблему (например [этот](https://serverfault.com/questions/225155/virtualbox-how-to-set-up-networking-so-both-host-and-guest-can-access-internet?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) вопрос на ServerFault, [статья](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-in-centos-7-rhel-7-fedora-26.html)). В итоге получаю в хроме "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT".

Стоит Windows 10, последняя версия VirtualBox с CentOS 7 на нем. Установил nginx на прослушивание порта 8080 (пробовал и 80), имя сервера `localhost`. Мне нужно подключиться к хоста (Windows) к nginx серверу.

Пробовал в настройках VirtualBox NAT, сетевой мост, виртуальный адаптер хоста и прочее, но безрезультатно. Пробовал установить статический IP в CentOS. Пробовал разрешить все входящие/исходящие запросы с IP: 192.168.56.1 (если верить VirtualBox, это локальный IP Windows) и 192.168.56.110 (соответственно, CentOs) в Брандмауэре Windows.

На самом CentOs я могу через curl получить ответ от nginx, так что это не с ним беда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось, необходимо было сбросить настройки `iptables` на CentOS (и это на почти чистой установке!). Почему?

```
sudo iptables -F
```

Answer (score 0):

Я использовал такие настройки при поднятии виртуальных серверов. 
Мне кажется, проблема в ip адресах, потому что на 192.168.x.1 всегда находится основной шлюз. Тебе нужно настроить VM так, чтобы виртуальная машина находилась в таком же статусе для роутера, как и основная машина (то есть, обе имели ip вида 192.168.56.xxx). Тогда ты точно сможешь подключиться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]